# jquery prompt message not working on enter key event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
case 'confirmyesno':
    $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.yesButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.noButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
    $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
        //alert("press yes button");
        $.alerts._hide();
        if( callback ) callback(true);
    });
    $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
        //alert("press no button");
        $.alerts._hide();
        if( callback ) callback(false);
    });
    $("#popup_ok").focus();
break;
```

My problem is that whenever I try to run this code on button click it works perfectly fine for me and ask me the question with yes/no options. But when I try to run the same code on enter key event of an input field than it does not display me the desired alert message and always clicks on the 'yes' button without displaying the alert message to the user. I am unable to find the reason that why it behaves differently in case of Button Press event and enter key event. Any ideas?

Comment: You have post your entire code.

Answer (score 1):

enter key is a button also... so that's a yes.. the question is??? how does the code know that the button is an enter key??

```
$("#popup_ok").click(function(event{
    if(event.keycode==13){
         $.alerts._hide();
         if( callback ) callback(true);
    }
})
```

Comment: I want it should prompt me for the YES/NO option in both cases i.e. on enter key event as well as on button click event.